# plt.colorbar() generates wrong ticks

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar

I'm currently working on plotting data using plt.imshow() and plt.colorbar() in Python.

```
class MidpointNormalize(mcolors.Normalize):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        mcolors.Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        v_ext = np.max( [ np.abs(self.vmin), np.abs(self.vmax) ] )
        x, y = [-v_ext, self.midpoint, v_ext], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y))

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(data, aspect='auto', norm=MidpointNormalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, midpoint=0), cmap='RdBu_r')
plt.colorbar()
for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(data.T):
    plt.text(x, y, f'{value}', ha='center',va='center', c= 'w' if value>0.5*vmax else 'k')
```

[image: Resulting plot]

In the resulting plot, I notice that although the highest value in the data is 8.29, the corresponding color on the colorbar is labeled as "10". I'm curious why this discrepancy occurs and how I might go about correcting it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I experimented with adding a mappable for the colorbar and using set_clim(). Additionally, I attempted to manually set the ticks, but given that the values vary for different datasets, I'm seeking a dynamic method to generate these ticks accurately.

Thank you JohanC for your quick answer.
To answer your first question: vmax and vmin are extracted from the data itself:

```
vmin, vmax = data.min(), data.max()
```

I tried it using seaborn as you suggested but I'm still not getting the colorbar as needed.

[Plot using seaborn.heatmap()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6icI.png)

Zero is displayed in the middle of the colorbar, although since the values range from -1.9 to 8.3 it should be closer to the bottom end.
In addition, the value -1.9 and 8.3 share the same level of darkness, but -1.9 should be as light as +1.9.

Thank you very much for further help!

Comment: Can you give provide dummy test data? Also, if `vmax` in your original code is 10, the colorbar will go from the given `vmin` to the given `vmax`.  If you want all your plots to use the exactly same norm, you need to supply the same `vmax` for all of them.  The colorbar will faithfully show the norm used, not the maximal value of the data.

Comment: You could strongly simplify the code via seaborn: `ax = sns.heatmap(data, norm=mpl.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=0), annot=True)`. Seaborn will automatically calculate the appropriate text color depending on the cell's color.  Your code is using an old partial implementation of `TwoSlopeNorm` that doesn't seem to work well when used with multiple colorbars.

Comment: This is doing what you asked it to.  If you want the interpolation past vmax to not collapse to vmax you need to set *right* to something bigger than vmax in `np.interp`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

Comment: Thank you @JodyKlymak for your reply. I see your point, but why does the colorbar try to make a tick at 10? The values only range up to 8.29.

Comment: Various optimizations, and also edge cases require it.